# unable to get fixed anchors working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement this solution [fixed anchors](https://pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header#comment-162990) and haven't been able to make it work.  Here's what I have so far.  Also, with position:fixed the links are appearing on the left when they should be on the right.

```css
.header{
  height:20px;
}

.right{
  float:right;
}

#section1{   
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}
#section2{  
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
#section3{  
  background-color:purple;
  color:white;
}
.size{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}

.anchor{
  display: block;
  height: 20px; /*same height as header*/
  margin-top: -20px; /*same height as header*/ 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='header' style="position: fixed; top: 0;">
   <div class='right' >
     <a  href ='#home'>home</a>
     <a  href ='#about'>about</a>
     <a  href ='#contact'>contact</a>
   </div> 
</div>


<span class='anchor' id='home'></span>
    <div id='section1' class='size'>home
    </div> 
<span class='anchor' id='about'></span>
    <div id='section2' class='size'>about
    </div>
<span class='anchor' id='contact'></span>
    <div id='section3' class='size'>contact
    </div>
```

Comment: you can add `right: 0;` to `.header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing methodology a bit here. I would separate the styles into one place instead of some inline - and some in the CSS and some as a helper class such as `.right`. Your span tags are `inline` - and can't have `block` things inside them - your `a` tags should also be `block` in this case... Hopefully, my example will show a smooth way to write the markup and CSS. - generally - if you are going to get serious about anchor links... you'll end up using JavaScript to calculate the header height - and add padding to the body so that it can sit on top / without covering up content + also help align the offset from the anchor link for each setting to ensure the padding is visually pleasing based on varying screen sized.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/sw5sLker/

markup

```
<header class='site-header'>

  <nav class='main-navigation'>
    <ul class='item-list'>
      <li class="item">
        <a class='link' href="#one">one</a>
      </li>

      <li class="item">
        <a class='link' href="#two">two</a>
      </li>

       <li class="item">
        <a class='link' href="#three">three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>


<section class='section one' id='one'>
  <h1>Section one</h1>
</section>

<section class='section two' id='two'>
  <h1>Section two</h1>
</section>

<section class='section three' id='three'>
  <h1>Section three</h1>
</section>
```

styles

```
body {
  margin: 0; /* reset */
  padding-top: 50px; 
  /* the size of the header... */
  /* usually done with JavaScript */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} /* reset */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
} /* reset */

.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.main-navigation .item-list {
  /* you could use flexbox - or inline-block+text-align - or floats */
  /*  if you use floats - put an overflow hidden here - and floats on the .item */
  /* shown in fiddle */
}

.main-navigation .item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-navigation .link {
  display: block; /* give these shape for fingers */
  padding: 1rem;
}

.section {
  min-height: 300px;
  color: black; /* 'all sections' */
  padding: 40px 10px; /* JS may be used here to determine offset */
}

.section.one, .section.three {
  background: lightgray; /* specific named areas */
}
```

Here is some example JS and another fiddle with that in place for fun.

```
// query for and cache elements you'll need
var $page = $('html, body');
var $body = $('body');
var headerHeight = $('.site-header').outerHeight();
var $navLink = $('.main-navigation').find('.link');

// some settings for you to change
var scrollSpeed = 500; // in miliseconds... set to 0 if you don't want a visible animation

// add the padding for the body based on the header height
$body.css('padding-top', headerHeight);

// add a click event listener
$navLink.on('click', function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    var anchorPosition = $(href).offset().top;
    var offsetAnchorPosition = anchorPosition - headerHeight;

    $page.animate({
        scrollTop:  offsetAnchorPosition
    }, scrollSpeed, function() {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });

    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c7xvpch8/ or  https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/zwbYPO/

Comment: this is just about perfect.  thank you.  one question, when this first loads the section one <h1> element is 50px below where it shows up when you click the link.  Is there a way to have it start up 50 px higher?  I can't seem to be able to that and still be able to not hide the <h1>'s when the links are pressed

Comment: I noticed that too - when I checked the debug version of the codepen. I'm not sure how to address that. It depends on your use-case. You could try the negative margin approach - and leave out the offset in the javascript... it's not a perfect playing-field, so at some-point - you'll have to do something hacky. Look at how documentation sites deal with anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float?v=control) in the size class, float is a really complicated parameter that mess a lot of features in the html, avoid him.

```
    .size{                                                                                                                                                   
      //float:left; remove him
      width:100%;
      height:700px;
    }
```

PS: You can do clear: both; in the end of sizes to try body bound all content together (it would be a **bad design**), but I strongly encourage you not use float in this case.

An example to you:

```
<style>
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
nav{
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

#section1{
background-color:blue;
color:white;
}
#section2{
background-color:green;
color:white;
}
#section3{
background-color:purple;
color:white;
}
.size{
width:100%;
height:700px;
}

.anchor{
display: block;
height: 20px; /*same height as header*/
margin-top: -20px; /*same height as header*/
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<nav>
    <a  href ='#home'>home</a>
    <a  href ='#about'>about</a>
    <a  href ='#contact'>contact</a>
</nav>


<span class='anchor' id='home'></span>
<div id='section1' class='size'>home
</div>
<span class='anchor' id='about'></span>
<div id='section2' class='size'>about
</div>
<span class='anchor' id='contact'></span>
<div id='section3' class='size'>contact
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Look my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/calexandrepcjr/pen/BRbaKd)

Comment: I upvoted as removing the float really helped.  The problem now is the links are still covered by the sections.

Comment: Your links are in a menu. Add position: absolute; and z-index: 999; top: 0; width: 100%; in the header class, remove div.right from there, align by text-align, padding, etc.

Brotip: use nav instead div.

Comment: when I try that the links just disappear

Comment: z-index: 999; is smelly

Comment: Your html,body was without height setted!

Comment: @sheriffderek it's just a quick example, i don't know all of structure of the program, can be multiple shades, the idea is: menu needs to be always showing in the most of cases.

Comment: snippet doesn't run